# Mouse event when clicking data title in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, bar-chart

I have created a simple horizontal barchart using JavaFX in Java 1.8. This displays correctly with a bottom legend, list of paths on the left and bars showing data grouped into 3 series. I would like to open a page that is dynamically populated based on the path chosen with the path on the left used as the link but I have not been able to find a way to create a mouse event when clicking on that data text.

In the sample code below the text retrieved by my "path" class's "getpath" method is what I would like to turn into a link.
Is there anyway to do this?

I've reviewed documentation on the BarChart and XYChart classes but I cannot find a way to get the value of a given item in the chart, and even if a did I cannot set an action event because the data value doesn't appear to have a specific node to set the event on.
Doing this with a button and/or drop down works as expected but i'd like to use the text built into the chart as a link.
Most of the other similar questions I have found referenced using a label for the title but that won't work in this case as the number of items in my chart will vary on the dataset passed into it.

```
//method for building chart
 protected BarChart getChart(ObservableList<myClass> chartData) {
    //Setup a horizontal barchart for displaying heat stats.

    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();

    final BarChart<Number,String> bc = 
        new BarChart<Number,String>(xAxis,yAxis);
    bc.setTitle("");
    xAxis.setLabel("Ops");  
    xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);
    yAxis.setLabel("NFS Exports with lock contention");        


    //Create series to hold data for each event type to show 
    XYChart.Series series1= new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("Series1");  
    XYChart.Series series2= new XYChart.Series();
    series2.setName("Series2");
    XYChart.Series series3= new XYChart.Series();
    series3.setName("Series3");       


    for (myClass path: chartData)
    {
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(path.getData1(), path.getPath()));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(path.getData2(), path.getPath()));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(path.getData3(), path.getPath()));
    }    
    bc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
    return bc;                
}


//method for getting sample data
 public ObservableList<myClass> getPathData()
    {
        ObservableList<myClass> exports = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        paths.add(new myClass("/path1", 12.0, 30.0, 62.0));
        paths.add(new myClass("/path2", 20.0, 43.0, 82.0));
        paths.add(new myClass("/path3", 0.0, 18.0, 23.0));
        paths.add(new myClass("/path4", 40.0, 26.0, 75.0));
        paths.add(new myClass("/path5", 8.0, 4.0, 5.0));
        return paths;
    }
```

What I would like is a way to make clicking on the path run a function passing in the path that was selected.

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).